# Error al Editar DataGridView

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015

Estoy trabajando en una app Windows Forms, me ha surgido un problema en un DataGridView, estoy trabajando en el evento CellEndEdit, en el cual cuando edito una fila y hago click en otra fila me lanza una Excepción.

La operación no es válida porque origina una llamada reentrante a la función SetCurrentCellAddressCore.

[image: Talla]

Mi código es el siguiente

```
private void dgvClasificacion_CellEndEdit(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
    {
        dgvClasificacion.Rows[e.RowIndex].ErrorText = string.Empty;
        ClasificacionTalla item = new ClasificacionTalla();

        DataGridViewRow row = dgvClasificacion.CurrentRow;
        item.ClasificacionTallaId = Convert.ToInt32(row.Cells[0].Value);
        item.Descripcion = Convert.ToString(row.Cells[1].Value);
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(item.Descripcion))
        {
            _repositoryClasificacionTalla.Create(item);

            dgvClasificacion.AutoGenerateColumns = false;
            listCT = _repositoryClasificacionTalla.GetAll().ToList(); => Traigo los datos desde la DB
            dgvClasificacion.DataSource = null;
            dgvClasificacion.Rows.Clear(); Borro los datos para que no se vuelvan a cargar los mismos, Es aquí el error.
            foreach (var c in listCT) ==> Cargo el DGV con los datos de la lista listCT
            {
                dgvClasificacion.Rows.Add(c.ClasificacionTallaId, c.Descripcion);
            }
        }
        else
            dgvClasificacion.Rows.Remove(dgvClasificacion.Rows[dgvClasificacion.Rows.Count -1]);
    }
```

Como le agrego datos al DGV desde el mismo control la carga lo hago por medio de un ForEach, al crear y actualizar un nuevo registro cargo la grilla como muestra el código, en la linea del código dgvClasificacion.Rows.Clear(); es donde manda la excepción.

[image: Error]

El error surge cuando estoy editando una fila y hago click en la otra fila, espero me puedan ayudar, gracias de antemano.

Encontré una supuesta solución pero no me esta funcionando es mas use un traductor de código.
[DGV](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/f824fbbf-9d08-4191-98d6-14903801acfc/operation-is-not-valid-because-it-results-in-a-reentrant-call-to-the-setcurrentcelladdresscore?forum=winformsdatacontrols)

Pero nunca entra al IF

```
public delegate void SetColumnIndex(int i);
    private void dgvClasificacion_CellEndEdit(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
    {
        if ((dgvClasificacion.CurrentCell.ColumnIndex
                != (dgvClasificacion.Columns.Count - 1)))
        {
            int nextindex = Math.Min((dgvClasificacion.Columns.Count - 1), (dgvClasificacion.CurrentCell.ColumnIndex + 1));
            SetColumnIndex method = new SetColumnIndex(Mymethod);
            dgvClasificacion.BeginInvoke(method, nextindex);


            dgvClasificacion.Rows[e.RowIndex].ErrorText = string.Empty;
            ClasificacionTalla ct = new ClasificacionTalla();

            DataGridViewRow fila = dgvClasificacion.CurrentRow;
            ct.ClasificacionTallaId = Convert.ToInt32(fila.Cells[0].Value);
            ct.Descripcion = Convert.ToString(fila.Cells[1].Value);
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(ct.Descripcion))
            {
                _repositoryClasificacionTalla.Create(ct);

                dgvClasificacion.AutoGenerateColumns = false;
                listCT = _repositoryClasificacionTalla.GetAll().ToList();
                //dgvClasificacion.Rows.Clear();
                foreach (var c in listCT)
                {
                    dgvClasificacion.Rows.Add(c.ClasificacionTallaId, c.Descripcion);
                }
            }
            else
                dgvClasificacion.Rows.Remove(dgvClasificacion.Rows[dgvClasificacion.Rows.Count - 1]);
        }
    }

    private void Mymethod(int columnIndex)
    {
            dgvClasificacion.CurrentCell = dgvClasificacion.CurrentRow.Cells[columnIndex];
            dgvClasificacion.BeginEdit(true);
    }
```

Comment: ¿Por qué asignas un null al DataSource? ¿La carga inicial la haces a través del DataSource?

Comment: Hola Asier, esa linea de código esta demás lo voy a borrar(Datasource), Así es la carga inicial lo hago con datasource a una lista pero al momento de volcar los datos a la grilla lo hago por medio de un foreach DGV.row.add

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solucionado

```
private void dgvClasificacion_CellEndEdit(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
    {
        this.BeginInvoke(new MethodInvoker(() =>
        {
            dgvClasificacion.Rows[e.RowIndex].ErrorText = string.Empty;
            ClasificacionTalla ct = new ClasificacionTalla();

            DataGridViewRow fila = dgvClasificacion.CurrentRow;
            ct.ClasificacionTallaId = Convert.ToInt32(fila.Cells[0].Value);
            ct.Descripcion = Convert.ToString(fila.Cells[1].Value);
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(ct.Descripcion))
            {
                _repositoryClasificacionTalla.Create(ct);

                dgvClasificacion.AutoGenerateColumns = false;
                listCT = _repositoryClasificacionTalla.GetAll().ToList();
                dgvClasificacion.Rows.Clear();
                foreach (var c in listCT)
                {
                    dgvClasificacion.Rows.Add(c.ClasificacionTallaId, c.Descripcion);
                }
            }
            else
                dgvClasificacion.Rows.Remove(dgvClasificacion.Rows[dgvClasificacion.Rows.Count - 1]);
        }));
    }
```